# How reload page in react just once after componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have some problem which i can't figure out an hours..

Here is what:

i'm using react and react router. 
I have a some component with own route like /about

and in this component i need to put some 3rd party javascript file which going with getting from some service some iframe to my page.

this service saying to me adding their script and rendering some div with specific id

i put this script to my component in `componentDidMount` method like that:

```
componentDidMount() {
   var loadScript = function(src) {
      var tag = document.createElement("script");
      tag.async = false;
      tag.src = src;
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      body.appendChild(tag);
    };
    loadScript("https://somewhere/js?for=myid");
}
```

and then in my render:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="content">
          <div id="iframe_app"></div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

till here everything is normal but this script tag calling just once.. 
when i change route eg going another page of my app and back this component script not working not appearing in network tab.

But if i'm hard refreshing window with `ctrl + r` anything works again.

so i don't know why is happening and because of that i think to refresh page on componentDidMount directly with

```
window.location.reload()
```

but that time it's working in loop so my page refreshing infinity

how i can figure out with this?

Answer (score 1):

if you really want this - add a unique parameter to the search string like loadScript("https://somewhere/js?for=myid&ver=" + Math.random()); // but you should use your own unique id generator instead of Math.random(), for example - this https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to load the scripts in the constructor before the component is already loaded. It isn’t a best practice use setState from componentDidMount

Comment: can u explain more?

Comment: Yes, each component has ha construction function which receives props as arguments. You could simply override this way: constructor(props){ super(props); loadingScripts(....);} then define loadingScript as method and you’re done. (Sorry for the indentation, but I’m from cellphone right now XD.